# Logical Equivalences not using a truth table

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am tasked by using logical equivalences to show $[q \land \neg(p \implies q)]$  is tautology or a contradiction. I know that by setting up a truth table that it is false. I did a truth table and confirmed it on wolfram! I am having a hard time showing the logical equivalences without a truth table. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

For $[q\text{ and }\sim(p\text{ implies }q)]$ to be true, we need $q$ to be true and $p$ implies $q$ to be false. Under what circumstances is $p$ implies $q$ false?

Edit: The statement $p$ implies $q$ is false only if $p$ is true and $q$ is false. Therefore for $[q\text{ and }\sim(p\text{ implies }q)]$ to be true, we need $[q\text{ and }(p\text{ and }\sim q)]$ to be true. Thus it is never true.

Comment: are you asking what law it would be?

Comment: Will edit with more details

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
q\land \sim(p\implies q)&\equiv q\land(p\land\sim q)\\&\equiv(q\land\sim q)\land p\equiv\color{red}{\text{Contradiction}}
\end{align}

Comment: is this the only law that would be used? Like i said before i know from the truth table that it is a contradiction. Is this the only logical equivalence?

Comment: @Jkoz Yes, Implication equivalence, De Morgan's negation, and Disjunctive syllogism, are all you need.  (Suhail combined the first two into one step.)

Comment: oh ok thank you so much